# Is it possible to set the background of individual lines inside a single table cell?

Tags: css, html-table, background-color

I wrote some CGI script that outputs a table with variable information.
One of the table cell can contain multiple strings, and I put each on a separate line by joining the strings with `<br/>`.

Then I thought it would improve readability if every second of such lines would have a different background color (I did that for complete table rows successfully).

So before joining them with `<br/>` I wrapped the strings in a `<span>` with alternating class names (like `re` for "row even" and `ro` for "row odd").
That worked, but the background end where the text ends, and not where the table cell ends.

Is it possible to set the background for the whole `<td>` line *without* putting a `<table>` inside the `<td>`?

The current output looks like this:

[image: Table output]

And the corresponding HTML fragement is (most styling is done via CSS):

```html
<table class="inf-tbl" summary="Server Information" title="Server Information" border="1"><caption class="inf-tbl">Server Information</caption>
<thead><tr><th colspan="2" class="inf-th">(redacted)</th></tr> <tr><th class="inf-th">Kategorie</th> <th class="inf-th">Eigenschaften</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><th class="inf-th">TLS Cipher</th><td class="inf-td">AES256-GCM-SHA384</td>
</tr> <tr><th class="inf-th">Unterstützte LDAP-Versionen</th><td class="inf-td"><span class="re">3</span></td>
</tr> <tr><th class="inf-th">Unterstützte Controls</th><td class="inf-td"><span class="ro">MANAGEDSAIT</span></td>
</tr> <tr><th class="inf-th">Unterstützte Features</th><td class="inf-td"><span class="re">ALL_OPATTS</span><br><span class="ro">MODIFY_INCREMENT</span></td>
</tr> <tr><th class="inf-th">Unterstützte Extensions</th><td class="inf-td"><span class="re">PASSWORD_MODIFY</span><br><span class="ro">START_TLS</span><br><span class="re">WHO_AM_I</span></td>
</tr> <tr><th class="inf-th">Unterstützte SASL-Mechanismen</th><td class="inf-td"><span class="ro">DIGEST-MD5</span><br><span class="re">GSSAPI</span></td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

## Revision 1

With the suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/74447412/6607497 I got this (note: I tweaked the left columns also to apply alternating background):

[image: Table layout after style changes]

The updated HTML code is this (`re` and `ro` are "row even" and "row odd", and `l` means "apply to whole 'line'"; there are some other classes that can be ignored):

```html
<table title="Server Information" summary="Server Information" class="inf-tbl" border="1"><caption class="inf-tbl">Server Information</caption>
<thead><tr><th colspan="2" class="inf-th">(redacted)</th></tr> <tr><th class="inf-th">Kategorie</th> <th class="inf-th">Eigenschaften</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><th class="inf-th">TLS Cipher</th><td class="inf-td">AES256-GCM-SHA384</td>
</tr> <tr><th class="inf-th ro">Unterstützte LDAP-Versionen</th><td class="inf-td"><span class="l ro">3</span></td>
</tr> <tr><th class="inf-th re">Unterstützte Controls</th><td class="inf-td"><span class="l re">MANAGEDSAIT</span></td>
</tr> <tr><th class="inf-th ro">Unterstützte Features</th><td class="inf-td"><span class="l ro">ALL_OPATTS</span><br><span class="l re">MODIFY_INCREMENT</span></td>
</tr> <tr><th class="inf-th re">Unterstützte Extensions</th><td class="inf-td"><span class="l ro">PASSWORD_MODIFY</span><br><span class="l re">START_TLS</span><br><span class="l ro">WHO_AM_I</span></td>
</tr> <tr><th class="inf-th ro">Unterstützte SASL-Mechanismen</th><td class="inf-td"><span class="l re">DIGEST-MD5</span><br><span class="l ro">GSSAPI</span></td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Finally there's the relevant CSS (I'm not good in CSS, obviously):

```css
table {
    background-color: white; color: black; margin-top: 1ex; margin-bottom: 1ex
}
td { padding-left: 1mm; padding-right: 1mm }
caption { caption-side: bottom; background-color: #c7ffc7 }
.l { display: inline-block; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;} /* fill whole line in cell */
.re, .ef-re, .ds-re { background-color: #e0e3e4 } /* 90% grey */
.ro, .ef-ro, .ds-ro { background-color: #ffffff }
table.inf-tbl { border-style: solid; border-width: thin;
    border-collapse: collapse }
.inf-td { padding-left: 0.5ex; padding-right: 0.5ex; font-family: sans-serif;
    vertical-align: top
}
.inf-th { padding-left: 0.5ex; padding-right: 0.5ex; font-weight: bolder;
    font-family: sans-serif; text-align: left; vertical-align: top
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting the gray section to extend to the end of the table cell?

Comment: remove the br and add display block to your spans

Comment: @Adam Yes, as described (I hope). See the yellow markings in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following to your CSS. It makes the span behave as an inline block that you can then set the width to the cell width.

```css
.re,
.ro {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.re {
  background-color: gray;
}

.ro {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table class="inf-tbl" summary="Server Information" title="Server Information" border="1">
  <caption class="inf-tbl">Server Information</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" class="inf-th">(redacted)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="inf-th">Kategorie</th>
      <th class="inf-th">Eigenschaften</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="inf-th">TLS Cipher</th>
      <td class="inf-td">AES256-GCM-SHA384</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="inf-th">Unterstützte LDAP-Versionen</th>
      <td class="inf-td"><span class="re">3</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="inf-th">Unterstützte Controls</th>
      <td class="inf-td"><span class="ro">MANAGEDSAIT</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="inf-th">Unterstützte Features</th>
      <td class="inf-td"><span class="re">ALL_OPATTS</span><br><span class="ro">MODIFY_INCREMENT</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="inf-th">Unterstützte Extensions</th>
      <td class="inf-td"><span class="re">PASSWORD_MODIFY</span><br><span class="ro">START_TLS</span><br><span class="re">WHO_AM_I</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="inf-th">Unterstützte SASL-Mechanismen</th>
      <td class="inf-td"><span class="ro">DIGEST-MD5</span><br><span class="re">GSSAPI</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Update 16 Nov 2022 to ensure padding is respected just add box-sizing:border-box. Example with some random padding added.

```css
.re,
.ro {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.re {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.ro {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table class="inf-tbl" summary="Server Information" title="Server Information" border="1">
  <caption class="inf-tbl">Server Information</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" class="inf-th">(redacted)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="inf-th">Kategorie</th>
      <th class="inf-th">Eigenschaften</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="inf-th">TLS Cipher</th>
      <td class="inf-td">AES256-GCM-SHA384</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="inf-th">Unterstützte LDAP-Versionen</th>
      <td class="inf-td"><span class="re">3</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="inf-th">Unterstützte Controls</th>
      <td class="inf-td"><span class="ro">MANAGEDSAIT</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="inf-th">Unterstützte Features</th>
      <td class="inf-td"><span class="re">ALL_OPATTS</span><br><span class="ro">MODIFY_INCREMENT</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="inf-th">Unterstützte Extensions</th>
      <td class="inf-td"><span class="re">PASSWORD_MODIFY</span><br><span class="ro">START_TLS</span><br><span class="re">WHO_AM_I</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="inf-th">Unterstützte SASL-Mechanismen</th>
      <td class="inf-td"><span class="ro">DIGEST-MD5</span><br><span class="re">GSSAPI</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: One minor question: If I use `padding-left` and `padding-right`, then `width: 100%` obeys the padding, while a `<th>` with `background-color` ignores it. Any chance to ignore the padding when processing the displayed block?

Comment: I've updated it with what I think you're after. Does the color have to be the exact width of the text or does it span the whole table cell?

Comment: Yes, I want it to fill the whole `<td>` if possible. I'm trying to update the question with the intermediate results and more info to make it clear what I'm after.